# python dictWriter not working in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

```
import Gvalues
with open('D:\Projects\log\pode.csv', 'w', newline='') as GValues.csv_file:

        writer1 = csv.DictWriter(GValues.csv_file, fieldnames=GValues.fieldnames)
        writer1.writeheader()
        while True:
             print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
             GetStats.get_stats_method(GValues.pair_name, GValues.depth_level)
             WriteCsv.write_csv(writer1)
```

Below code is working fine, but when I put it in while loop it is failing. I am able to run the program but there is not data in csv file. I am not making any changes except removing the while loop and adjusting the tab.

```
import Gvalues
with open('D:\Projects\log\pode.csv', 'w', newline='') as GValues.csv_file:

        writer1 = csv.DictWriter(GValues.csv_file, fieldnames=GValues.fieldnames)
        writer1.writeheader()
        print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
        GetStats.get_stats_method(GValues.pair_name, GValues.depth_level)
        WriteCsv.write_csv(writer1)
```

Comment: are you aware that this is an infinite loop? the csv file _has_ to be closed at some point.

Comment: yes. I am running with pycharm and closing it forcefully

Comment: by clicking stop program

Comment: have you tried a non-infinite loop?

Comment: also be careful with backslashes in strings. Use raw prefix: `r'D:\Projects\log\pode.csv'`

Comment: Yup it is working. How do I make it write with infinite loop. I dont mind loosing last records when I press stop or force quit.

Comment: I suggest that you call `GValues.csv_file.flush()` after writing the line

Comment: Thank you about that. It worked